# Is there a feature that will notify me about particular questions that I may be able to answer?

Tags: feature-request

I've spent a fair amount of time learning just the basics of computer science in the past few months. And, it would be more beneficial for me to actually try to answer questions instead of asking them. (good challenge)

### Question

Is there a feature that will notify me by email for certain questions containing tags and keywords? So that I may be able to answer them.
If not, may we get this feature?

Comment: The state of the help center is atrocious. [Bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336232/156248).

Comment: The help center has been updated and now reflects the current feature set: [cs.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- [create custom filters](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions?edited=true);
- watch tags, configured at `https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/$userid`;
- [create a fancy search](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/searching) and bookmark it;
- subscribe to tag RSS feeds like e.g. `https://cs.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=algorithms+sorting&sort=newest`.